Window Resizing Issues with Custom Title Bar
I'm developing a custom media player application using PySide6. I've successfully implemented a custom title bar with buttons for minimizing, maximizing, and closing the window. However, after adding the custom title bar, the window has become unresponsive to resizing attempts.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QRect
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget, QSizePolicy, QFileDialog, QLineEdit, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel

class NordMediaPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize the dragging state
        self._dragging = False
        self._drag_position = None
        
        self.setWindowTitle("shax0")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # Remove original title bar
        self.resize(250, 250)  # Set default window size to 250x250
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ECEFF4; color: #2E3440;")  # Light Nord theme

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # Main layout with control bar, cover art, and command bar
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.setSpacing(0)

        # Create the layout container for the title bar, cover art, and control bar
        self.mainContainer = QWidget(self)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.mainContainer)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Title bar
        self.titleBar = self.createTitleBar()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.titleBar)

        # Cover art area
        self.coverArt = self.createCoverArt()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.coverArt)

        # Control bar
        self.controlBar = self.createControlBar()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.controlBar)

        # Create terminal command bar (text pad for command input)
        self.commandBar = QLineEdit(self)
        self.commandBar.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2E3440; color: #ECEFF4; font-family: Mononoki; font-size: 14px; border: none;")
        self.commandBar.setPlaceholderText("Enter command...")
        self.commandBar.setFixedHeight(30)  # Height of the command bar
        self.commandBar.setVisible(False)  # Initially hidden
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.commandBar)

        # Create file explorer widget to be shown when "f" command is pressed
        self.fileExplorerWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.fileExplorerWidget.setVisible(False)  # Start with file explorer hidden
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.fileExplorerWidget)

        # Create a QFileSystemModel and QTreeView for file explorer
        self.fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath('')

        self.fileExplorerView = QTreeView(self)
        self.fileExplorerView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
        self.fileExplorerView.setRootIndex(self.fileSystemModel.index(''))  # Show the root directory
        self.fileExplorerView.setColumnWidth(0, 250)  # Adjust column width
        self.fileExplorerView.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ECEFF4; color: #2E3440; font-family: Mononoki; font-size: 12px;")
        self.fileExplorerWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.fileExplorerWidget.layout().addWidget(self.fileExplorerView)

        # Set main layout
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainContainer)

        # Connect Enter key press to process the command
        self.commandBar.returnPressed.connect(self.processCommand)

    def createTitleBar(self):
        """Create a custom title bar with the original Nord theme colors in right-to-left direction."""
        titleBarWidget = QWidget(self)
        titleBarLayout = QHBoxLayout(titleBarWidget)
        titleBarLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        titleBarLayout.setSpacing(1)  # Reduced horizontal space between buttons to 1 pixel

        # Set layout direction to Right-To-Left (RTL)
        titleBarLayout.setDirection(QHBoxLayout.RightToLeft)  # Corrected this line

        # Title bar height
        buttonHeight = 35
        buttonWidth = 40  # Reduced width of buttons

        titleBarWidget.setFixedHeight(buttonHeight)

        # App icon (Ensure you have a valid path for this image)
        appIcon = QLabel()
        appIcon.setPixmap(QPixmap("playback/sine.png").scaled(48, 48, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))  # Replace with valid path
        titleBarLayout.addWidget(appIcon)

        # App title
        appTitle = QLabel("shax0")
        appTitle.setStyleSheet("font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #2E3440; font-family: Mononoki;")
        titleBarLayout.addWidget(appTitle)

        titleBarLayout.addStretch()

        # Minimize button
        minimizeButton = self.createTitleBarButton("playback/min.png", "Minimize", buttonHeight, buttonWidth)  # Ensure valid image path
        minimizeButton.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        titleBarLayout.addWidget(minimizeButton)

        # Maximize button
        maximizeButton = self.createTitleBarButton("playback/max.png", "Maximize", buttonHeight, buttonWidth)  # Ensure valid image path
        maximizeButton.clicked.connect(self.toggleMaximizeRestore)
        titleBarLayout.addWidget(maximizeButton)

        # Close button (positioned to the far left in RTL)
        closeButton = self.createTitleBarButton("playback/close.png", "Close", buttonHeight, buttonWidth)  # Ensure valid image path
        closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        titleBarLayout.addWidget(closeButton)

        titleBarWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D8DEE9; border: none;")

        return titleBarWidget

    def createTitleBarButton(self, iconPath, tooltip, buttonHeight, buttonWidth):
        """Create a button for the title bar."""
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setIcon(QIcon(iconPath))
        button.setToolTip(tooltip)
        button.setFixedSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
        button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #BF616A;
            }
        """)

        # Set icon size to 30% of the button height
        button.setIconSize(QSize(buttonHeight * 0.3, buttonHeight * 0.3))  # Reduced size (30% of button height)

        return button

    def createCoverArt(self):
        """Create a placeholder for the cover art with Light Nord theme."""
        coverArtWidget = QLabel()
        coverArtWidget.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("playback/cover_art_placeholder.png").scaled(200, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))  # Replace with valid path
        coverArtWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        coverArtWidget.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #ECEFF4;
            border: none;
            font-family: Mononoki;
            color: #2E3440;
            font-size: 12px;
        """)
        coverArtWidget.setText("shax0")
        return coverArtWidget

    def createControlBar(self):
        """Create the control bar with evenly distributed icons."""
        controlBarWidget = QWidget(self)
        controlBarLayout = QHBoxLayout(controlBarWidget)
        controlBarLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlBarLayout.setSpacing(0)

        buttonHeight = 35

        # Control buttons
        controls = [
            ("playback/play.png", "Play"),
            ("playback/rwd.png", "Rewind"),
            ("playback/stop.png", "Stop"),
            ("playback/fwd.png", "Fast Forward"),
            ("playback/shuffle.png", "Shuffle"),
            ("playback/wave.png", "Wave"),
            ("playback/terminal.png", "Terminal"),
        ]

        for iconPath, tooltip in controls:
            button = self.createControlButton(iconPath, tooltip, buttonHeight)
            controlBarLayout.addWidget(button)

        controlBarWidget.setFixedHeight(buttonHeight)
        controlBarWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D8DEE9; border: none;")
        return controlBarWidget

    def createControlButton(self, iconPath, tooltip, buttonHeight):
        """Create a control button."""
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setIcon(QIcon(iconPath))
        button.setToolTip(tooltip)
        button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #E5E9F0;
            }
        """)
        button.setIconSize(QSize(buttonHeight * 0.6, buttonHeight * 0.6))
        if tooltip == "Terminal":
            button.clicked.connect(self.toggleCommandBar)  # Connect Terminal button to toggle visibility
        return button

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Track mouse press to enable dragging the window."""
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.titleBar.geometry().contains(event.pos()):
            self._dragging = True
            self._drag_position = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """Drag window based on mouse movement."""
        if self._dragging:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self._drag_position)
            event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """Stop dragging the window."""
        self._dragging = False

    def toggleMaximizeRestore(self):
        """Toggle between maximizing and restoring the window."""
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()  # Restore the window to its previous size
        else:
            self.showMaximized()  # Maximize the window

    def toggleCommandBar(self):
        """Toggle command bar visibility."""
        self.commandBar.setVisible(not self.commandBar.isVisible())

    def processCommand(self):
        """Process the command entered in the command bar."""
        command = self.commandBar.text().strip()
        if command == 'f':
            self.openFileExplorer()
        elif command == 't':
            self.commandBar.clear()
            self.commandBar.setVisible(False)
        elif command == 'p':
            self.commandBar.clear()
            self.commandBar.setVisible(False)

    def openFileExplorer(self):
        """Open the file explorer when the 'f' command is entered."""
        self.fileExplorerWidget.setVisible(True)
        self.commandBar.clear()
        self.commandBar.setVisible(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NordMediaPlayer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I've tried the following approaches to enable resizing, but none have worked:
Setting QSizeGrip: I attempted to add QSizeGrip widgets to the window corners, but they had no effect.
Overriding window resize events: I tried overriding resizeEvent, but it didn't seem to be called when attempting to resize the window.
I suspect that the way I'm handling mouse events for dragging the window might be interfering with the window's resizing behavior.
Could anyone please provide guidance on how to make the window resizable again while maintaining the custom title bar?
Additional Notes:
I'm using PySide6 on a Linux system.
I've searched for similar issues online, but haven't found a solution that works for my specific case.
I appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer.
I believe its also the last button blocking the edge and also causing a problem where the cursor can change and affect because its using resources for the hover detection.

With "the window has become unresponsive to resizing attempts" are you referring to the capability of resizing the window by dragging its edges with the mouse? Because if that's the case, then the problem is not caused by the title bar, but by the usage of the FramelessWindowHint flag, which completely removes frame borders (hence the name), as the documentation explains: "Produces a borderless window. The user cannot move or resize a borderless window via the window system". Please show how you tried to use QSizeGrip.

yes but i need this to create the custom titlebar, but your correct. i tried mouseevents is there no way to do this with a cusom titlebar.

Note that you seem to have misunderstood how overriding resizeEvent() would work: a QResizeEvent is not received when one attempts to resize a widget: it's received when it has already been resized. The purpose of resizeEvent() is to do something after the widget is resized. In your case, it would be necessary to properly place QSizeGrips at the right geometries. See the answer to the question marked as duplicated.

Also, if you use a layout without margins, there is no appropriate way to allow resizing in corners occupied by buttons: if there is a button, then the button should take precedence over any mouse event (otherwise it wouldn't be appropriate nor intuitive). If you can live without the corner resizing near those buttons, then just add the size grips at the other corners; otherwise, you must use a margin for the layout.

can i use win32 if not would i have to use something like winui or electron to do the frontend

No idea, I don't use Windows.
